# Why jQuery html works like replaceWith when using with form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have form with id `push-message-form` and ajax call to server returns new form html to replace with. `push-message-form` id set on form itself, like:

```
<form id='push-message-form'>form content</form>
```

and ajax response html looks same.

From jQuery docs I understood that: html() will replaces the contents of the element, while replaceWith() replaces the actual element.

http://api.jquery.com/html/

http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

But I'm using

```
$('#push-message-form').html('<form id='push-message-form'>content</form>')
```

and it replaces form itself (whilst it should add another form inside current one).

The question is why html() works as replaceWith() in this case?

**Update**

Some answers suggests use append, sorry if it's not clear. But I don't want to append. I want to replace form with new one returned from server (keeping it's id), and replaceWith() does work just fine.

The question is why html() works too here. Since it should replace only content, but it replaces  tag too.

Comment: Try adding one with a different ID.  You are breaking HTML compliance by using the same ID twice.

Comment: Why you are doing this?.why you want to append form with the same id inside previous form.I suggest to use append() method and use new form id.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `.append()` to add content to the container calling `.html()` is going to replace whatever is inside that container with the value you enter:

Also you're trying to append the form with the same `id` so you should use a class or change the id name

This:

```
$('#push-message-form').append('<form class="push-message-form">content</form>')
```

Instead of this:

```
$('#push-message-form').html('<form id='push-message-form'>content</form>')
```

Comment: This will nest a new form within itself with the same ID.  That's not HTML compliant and will cause problems.

Comment: I know, but thats what OP has, updating my post to reflect that

Comment: @AlmasSapargali you would have to recreate this issue some how, there is no case in which html would replace the the wrapper too. Unless you are using the same `id` as the parent of form and that is being triggered instead of the actual `form` element

Comment: @jmore009 I'm pretty sure that happened, I was wondering too. Though on another form html() creates another form inside (buggy, but expected).

Answer (score 0):

`.html()` acutally clears the HTML inside the element & then places your new HTML in it. While you need `.append()` to actually make you new HTML added in the Current HTML

```
$('#push-message-form').append('<form id='new-form-id'>content</form>')
```